# <tr> onclick works, but I also want a visual effect

Tags: javascript, android, html

In an android app, I have a tr onclick="HitRow(this,'http://www.test.com');" ... to go to another url when the entire table row is clicked. This works fine.

```
    function HitRow(cell,loc) 
        { 
        window.location.href = loc;
        cell.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
```

However I also want a visual click on the row. I tried setting the background color with cell.style.backgroundColor, but this works after the user has navigated away and/or it's momentarily flashing in a confusing way.

What I would ideally want is the color to be changed on touch down, and on touch up the href to be executed. Can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use unobtrusive Javascript, [touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Touch_events) and [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) to do this:

**Markup:**

```
<tr data-url="http://www.google.com">

</tr>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var tr = document.querySelector("tr");
tr.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
});
tr.addEventListener("touchend", function() {
    window.location.href = this.getAttribute("data-url");
});
```

If you have multiple `tr` elements, you'll want to use `document.querySelectorAll` instead and loop through them:

```
var i;
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("tr[data-url]");
for(i=elements.length;i--) {
    var element = elements[i];
    element.addEventListener("touchstart", doTouchStart);
    element.addEventListener("touchend", doTouchEnd);
}

function doTouchStart() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function doTouchEnd() {
    window.location.href = this.getAttribute("data-url");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

instead of this :

```
function HitRow(cell,loc) 
            { 
            window.location.href = loc;
            cell.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            }
```

try this :

```
function HitRow(cell,loc) 
        { 
        cell.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        window.location.href = loc;

        }
```